# How to substitute already removed "dynamic location bookmark" firefox feature?

Tags: firefox, search, bookmarks

In the past firefox had ability to save bookmarks with dynamic url parts and initiate them with assigned shortcuts like described here (clickable, points to feature description):

[image]

For example I could search on superuser.com by setting bookmark's location like *https://superuser.com/search?q=%s*, set *sus* keyword for it and search superuser.com from address entering *sus mysearchstring*. But now this ability has gone. There is something similar in firefox options, but I can't tweak it to may needs:

[image]

Is there any substitute for old "dynamic bookmarks" firefox feature ?

Answer (score 2):

For search engines and your example of superuser.com:

1. Open the website, click the 3-dot at the right of the address bar.
2. Click on Add Search Engine.

[image]

3. Go to Options -> Search -> Search shortcuts. Superuser entry will be among the search  engines but its keyword will be empty.

[image]

4. Double-click on the empty box, enter `@sus`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

5. To search on superuser from the address bar, enter `@sus` then the term(s) you are looking for.